# How to mount WebDAV share programmatically on Windows 7/Vista without assigning drive letter?

Tags: windows, networking, location, webdav

I need to mount WebDAV share programmatically on Windows 7/Vista without assigning drive letter. I know

```
net use
```

and

```
WScript.CreateObject('WScript.Network').MapNetworkDrive('E:', 'http://server/');
```

can mount WebDAV but they require drive letter. Any chance to mount WebDAV without assigning drive letter? For example Add Network Location Wizard can do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this to provide the credentials:

```
net use \\www.foobar.baz\folder /USER:Foo /PASS:Bar
```

Then, you can use the WebDAV drive by its UNC name (`myCoolCommand.exe \\www.foobar.baz\folder`)

Comment: Thank you Paul, your answer was really helpful. Now I need to show the login dialog to user, but only if it server is requesting authentication. I do not know the credentials and cannot hardcode them. In fact I need exactly the same behavior as Add Network Location Wizard. Are there any chance to call the same Windows API  Add Network Location is using?

Comment: Are you using actual code (i.e. not script)?  You can used Credential Manager to pop up a similar looking dialog, collect the user/pass, then pass it to net use

Comment: I am using a Java applet. I thought there may a way to avoid login dialog programming.